# Prove an analytic automorphism does not have essential singularity at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently struggling with above question.

I know from Picard's Great Theorem that an analytic function cannot be injective in the deleted neighborhood of its essential singularity. I believe that this is an important observation to proving above statement. So can anybody enlighten me about how I should approach the problem based on that result? Assume the analytic automorphism is from *C* to *C*.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's all. An automorphism should be in particular injective.

Comment: $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(1/z)}$ is bounded for $0<|z| \le 1/(2f^{-1}(0))$ thus $z^2 g(z)$ is holomorphic and analytic, so is $g(z)$, let $n\ge 0$ be the order of its zero at $z=0$, then $h(z)=\frac{f(z)-\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(m)}(0) }{m!} z^m}{z^n}$ is entire and bounded.

Comment: @logarithm   So is it because the function f is not injective in the neighborhood of infinity, which contradicts the fact that f is bijective?

Comment: Yes, an automorphism is, in particular a function with an inverse.

Comment: @logarithm  I see... So does it imply that an analytic automorphism does not have any essential singularity in the complex domain as above argument can be applied to any other point beside infinity ?

Comment: @reuns sorry...I am new to this subject. Could you explain how h(z) is related to above problem?

Comment: Do you see why $g(z)$ is bounded ? For $h(z)$ use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis) you can use the injectivity to show $n=1$